# How to help my cat loose weight

Tags: cats, diet, exercise

My 5 year old female cat (Circus) is very overweight. Bloodwork is fine - vet says she just likes food and is getting less exercise as she gets bigger. She is indoor/outdoor but doesn't leave the yard. The autofeeder didn't work. I'm giving the recommended amount of dry and wet food but her litter mate (Tyto, a male) is an ideal weight and has food insecurity so we have to leave food out for him at all times otherwise his behavior is so bad he doesn't let us sleep. We tried putting his food somewhere she couldn't reach (she's so big she can't jump much any more) but it triggered his food anxiety so much he didn't once eat it on his own for the week trial - I had to place him in front of his food every time which doesn't work at night. The feeders that open for only a cat wearing a collar didn't work because she pushes him away and eats his food. I'm at a loss at what to try next. At this point her weight increase is so fast and much (2 lbs. in the past 3 months) that she'll have serious health issues in no time and a limited lifespan. It's so sad and I don't know what to do.